# XML file in memory and not as a file on disk

Tags: java, xml, file, download, wicket

I would like to create a XML file, that will be offered to a user as a download link (Wicket and TransformerFactory for XSLT).
At the moment, I use the File class. However, I don't want to create a file on the server. The file should only exist in memory. Can someone show me how I can accomplish this?
Thanks!

My current code:

```
Reader reader = new StringReader("DATA");
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("EXCEL.xsl"));
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
File file= new File("FILE.xml");                
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(reader), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(file)));
```

Other class:

```
File file = new File("file");
add(new DownloadLink("download", file, "XML.xml"));
```

Comment: With the File class, you do not have a chance to accomplish this as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

you could start with this (not sure if this is completely correct - can't check right now)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream oStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(reader), new StreamResult(oStream))
byte[] xmlResult = oStream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: You might even want to consider streaming directly back to the client (using `response.getOutputStream()` in a Servlet, not sure how to access the response outputstream in Wicket).

Comment: if we had talked about a simple servlet i would have just suggested that

Comment: Don't call `toString()` on a ByteArrayOutputStream. Call `toByteArray()` instead.

Comment: Everyone thanks for the help. I used the code above to create a file (stream). Now I would like to include the file in a AjaxDownload option (https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/ajax-update-and-file-download-in-one-blow.html).  The problem left is that I have to transform the byte[] array to IResourceStream. How can I accomplish this?